# Oracle 11g error when starting trace for other session

Tags: oracle

In Oracle 11g, I tried to trace a session, but failed. The tool is SQL Developer. I don't have permissions ? but I can query v$session.

Thanks

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE(session_id=>72, 
                                         serial_num=>36449, 
                                         waits=>TRUE, 
                                         binds=>TRUE);
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_MONITOR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the `execute` privilege for the `dbms_monitor` package.

Ask your DBA to run

```
GRANT execute ON dbms_monitor TO your_username;
```

Comment: how can I list all privileges I have and what role I am ?